# Keep getting this error E902 EOF on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def computepay(hours, rate):
    if hours > 40.0:
        p = rate * 40.0


p = p+(1.5*rate*(hours-40))
else:
    p = rate*hours
return p
hours = float(input("Enter worked hours: "))
rate = float(input("Enter Pay rate per hour: "))
print computepay(hours, rate))
```

I am getting E902 - EOF in multi-line statement on the def computepay.

Comment: Could be an indentation error: you've definitely copied your code over correctly?

Comment: it is still an indendation issue

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran everything is working perfectly now.Thanks

Comment: @jcoppens Don’t edit to fix the indentation because in this case, the indentation _is_ part of the problem. After your edit, the code in the question now becomes the same as the code in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all welcome to Stackoverflow.
And here is your code after I corrected with proper indentation and brackets.
It should work:

```
def computepay(hours, rate):
    if hours > 40.0:
        p = rate * 40.0
        p = p+(1.5*rate*(hours-40))
    else:
        p = rate*hours
    return p
hours = float(input("Enter worked hours: "))
rate = float(input("Enter Pay rate per hour: "))
print(computepay(hours, rate))
```